# MySQL SELECT MAX() query

Tags: android, mysql, max

I have a transactiontable where I insert transactions and also save the current total (or balance) for every transaction. My table looks like this:
transactiontable

[image]

Here,

- transaction_id is the unique primary key
- *user_id_1* is the user_id received with POST by my PHP file
- *user_id_2* is the friend's id that user_id_1 has transacted with
- transaction_code is 0 for receive money (decreases current_total) and 1 for give money (increases current_total)
- transaction_status 1 indicates a confirmed transaction

I want to retrieve the most recent current total for every friend given a user_id using a select operation. Something like this for user_id_1 = '26' in the above table:

```
user_id_2 current_total
1         375  
27        350
```

So far I have come up with this but it doesnt work as intended:

```
select user_id_2, current_total from transactiontable where user_id_1 = '$user_id' and (transaction_id=(SELECT MAX(transaction_id)) and transaction_status = '1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a GROUP BY clause to find the highest ID, then join that with your original table

Something like this:

```
SELECT user_id_2, current_total 
    FROM transactiontable 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(transaction_id) AS maxID 
        FROM transactiontable 
        WHERE user_id_1 = '26' 
        AND transaction_status = '1' GROUP BY user_id_2 
    ) AS m 
    ON transaction_id=maxID
```

Comment: I think this is retrieving the max(current_total) for every user_id_2. I want it to retrieve the current total associated with the max(transaction_id) for every user_id_2.